# Segmentation of users on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm managing a Facebook app, and I want to get details about my users that are logged in through Facebook so I could send them messages depending on their demographic groups.

I want to segment them based on information like their age group, country, gender, language, and any other similar things. How can I do this? I tried looking at the personal information that the Facebook API provides, but I could only see age range, and it only said above 21 for a user who's 28 years old, without any upper limit, which is quite useless.